# How to use subproject with Apportable?

Tags: subproject, apportable

Currently Apportable cannot reference C++ classes in subproject.

```
Dexing classes.
Archiving Build/android-armeabi-debug/AAAA/apk/lib/armeabi/libconfig.a
Indexing Build/android-armeabi-debug/AAAA/apk/lib/armeabi/libconfig.a
Linking Build/android-armeabi-debug/AAAA/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so
/Users/Eonil/Desktop/Apportable Bug Reporting/2013-06-21/aaaa2/AAAA/AAAA/main.mm:18: error: undefined reference to 'BBBB::bbbb()'
scons: *** [Build/android-armeabi-debug/AAAA/apk/lib/armeabi/libverde.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'" in <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile instance at 0x10a1e8b90>> ignored
Erionirr:AAAA Eonil$
```

I think this needs additional setup, but I cannot figure it out. Specifically, in this section in `configuration.json` file.

```
//Sub projects
"modules": [],
```

How can I make Apportable build and link subproject correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be able to add target dependancies in your xcode build phases and then link that sub-project in.
Else if you want to manually specify an added module the layout is as follows:

```
{
    "project": "project_name", 
    "build_cwd": "../some_dir", 
    "target": "the_target_of_the", 
    "project_config": "Release"
},
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little further?